# Confused about a Russian abbreviation for a particular radioactive source

Tags: физика, сокращения

I was looking at [this website](http://zaokvant.ru/products/radioactive-sources) which lists various radioisotope products.

Under "Изотоп Иридий-192" (Iridium Isotope-192), it lists several items such as "ГИИД-1".  But I can't for the life of me understand what "ГИИД-1" stands for.

The English format of this website is completely different from the Russian one, and I haven't been able to get anything from Google.

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a name. And only the authors know what exactly it means. Ask them.
We can only guess:

- `Г` - Гамма
- `И` - Излучатель
- `И` - Иридиевый
- `Д-1` - ???

Comment: "ИД" stands for "иридий" and "1" is just a model.

Comment: First `И` could be `источник`

Comment: The table (from the document in the other answer) suggests that Д-1 is a diameter number.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this document](http://www.isotop.ru/files/treecontent/nodes/attaches/0/95/noname..pdf) in a Google search for `ГИИД`. You can find detailed information on page 9 of the document. `ГИИД-1` is a device used as a source of gamma rays in radiography. The device is a steel container with an isotope iridium-192 inside. There are several devices, the first being `ГИИД-1`.

The meaning of the word `ГИИД` is explained in another response, but my guess is that it's `источник`, not `излучатель`: "Гамма-источник иридиевый", "1" - I think, is just a model number.